# MVC required field validation when lost focus

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

The ASP.NET MVC [Required] Validation only trigger in one of the following conditions:
1) Form submission 
2) Tab into the field -> Enter some text -> Tab out -> Tab back into the field -> Remove the text -> Tab out.

I would like to make if to be trigger in this way: 
Tab into the field -> Tab out -> Trigger validation

How could this be done?

Comment: It is possible....Have you tried anything post your code?

Comment: Client side validation library like jquery validation will achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is by design. From the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

> Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages – they won't get bugged before having the chance to actually enter a correct value
>   Once a field is marked invalid, it is eagerly validated: As soon as the user has entered the necessary value, the error message is removed

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery. You can use [focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) or [blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).
Take a look at examples, might help.